# Finding volume of a cone using its cross section using integration

Tags: integration

> The base of the cone is a circle with radius $r$ and the height of the cone is $h$

To derive the volume of the cone, I will need to find the cross sectional area of the circle (horizontal cross section)

Let $s$ be the radius of the small circle, and $x$ be the distance of the cross section to the base of the triangle.

Using similar triangles: $\frac{s}{r} = \frac{h-x}{h}$

therefore $s = r (\frac{h-x}{h})$

Area of the cross section = $\pi (s)^2 = \pi r^2 (1 - \frac{x}{h})^2$

Using this information of the area of cross section, integrate $\int_0^h (\pi r^2 (1 - \frac{x}{h})^2) dx$

This integration does not give me the volume of the cone: $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$

Next, the volume of the cone could also be $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h \sin \theta$

For this, we are still taking "horizontal cross sections of the cone but integrating from 0 to $h\sin \theta$, this does not give me $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h \sin \theta$

Comment: Evaluate the first integral (by method 1) properly. You should get the correct result.

Comment: If you have trouble evaluating the integral, you obtain an easier one if you invert the cone (so that it's standing on its point), since then $s=\frac{rx}{h}$ and the integrand becomes $\frac{\pi r^2}{h^2}x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

> Using this information of the area of cross section, integrate $\int_0^h (\pi r^2 (1 - \frac{x}{h})^2) dx$

> This integration does not give me the volume of the cone: $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$

Let $y=1-x/h$ then $dy=-dx/h$ and $\int^1_0 y^2 dy = 1/3$ so it does indeed give you that. Explicitly,

$$\int_0^h (\pi r^2 (1 - \frac{x}{h})^2) dx
=\pi r^2\int_0^h (1-x/h)^2dx\\
=\pi r^2\int_1^0 (-h) y^2 dy\\
=\pi r^2 h\int_0^1 y^2 dy\\
=\pi r^2 h {y^3\over3}\Biggr|_0^1 
$$

> Next, the volume of the cone could also be $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h \sin \theta$

Would be useful to say what $\theta$ is.

Comment: $\theta \le \pi/2$